# SQL Server table variable vs string query performance

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure, I am using a `while` loop for creating dynamic insertions. I need to save one row for each loop and the end save that rows in the database. My question is what is better? Save the new row in a table variable or contact each row to a `varchar` query and then to a insert to the database?

Comment: Better how? Faster? Less I/O? More maintainable? Is there a reason you cannot simply try both and see which one you prefer?

Comment: Surely you don't really need a loop to insert data??? This is one of the oldest excuses for using a loop ever and almost every time they are not needed. How about you post your code and we can show you how to do it in a single insert statement instead of looping.

Comment: hi @SeanLange I think the loop is nesesary because I calculate a lot of values of finnancial information using, for example 20 diferent tables, if for example in the 34 loop the formula need a new value I added it using if statements, query of queries and so on..

Comment: I guess we will have to agree to disagree on that one. :) I would bet a set based solution could be done for this but if you are cool with it that is all that matters.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  It is usually faster to send a few decent sized transactions rather than lots of single row transactions or one very large transaction.

The only way to really know is to benchmark it and see.  On a similar type of problem I had a while back, it worked out to about 5000 rows being inserted at once gave the best overall performance with the least amount of blocking.  Row by row is probably the worst way to do it in most every case though.